# IIS 8.5 Import Site Bindings?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8, iis-8.5

Is there a way that I can import a list of bindings for a site in IIS 8.5?

I have 160+ bindings to add to one site, all the same IP, and I'd really love to be able to do it non-manually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell!  New-WebBinding does what I think you want.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790567.aspx

New-WebBinding [[-Name] ] [-Protocol ] [-Port ] [-IPAddress ] [-HostHeader ] [-Force] [-WarningAction ] [-WarningVariable ] []

Comment: thanks bud. Unaware of that one :)  Going to write a script to parse my CSV, loop them, and do this.   Thanks! :)